# Ex: Computing a vector of logicals that is true when x[i]>0

Tags: r

With x a vector of numbers, write code in R to compute a vector y of logicals such that y[i] is TRUE whenever x[i] > 0.

I tried to answer in the following way:

```
x<-c(-1,0,1,2)
y<-logical(length(x))

for (i in 1:length(x)){
  y[i]-x[i]>0
  
 }
```

But it is printing a vector y of everything false.

If I try:

```
y-x>0
```

It does not work either.

**Question:**

How should I solve this apparently simple problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `y <- x>0`

Comment: In both shown ways you use `-` where you should have used `<-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long but hopefully easy to understand.

```
for(i in 1:length(x)){

  if(x[i] > 0){
    y[i] <- TRUE

  } else {
    y[i] <- FALSE
  }
}
```